# MySQL - Select First/Last Different Row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So I've got a table with this basic structure (I've tried to eliminate irrelevant fields):

```
EmpID  EventDate   Timestamp            State   State_Time
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 00:00:00  a       01:00:00
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 01:00:00  a       01:00:00
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 02:00:00  a       01:00:00
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 03:00:00  a       01:00:00
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 04:00:00  a       00:24:00
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 04:24:00  b       00:03:00      1*
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 04:27:00  c       00:33:00      2*
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 05:00:00  c       01:00:00
1111   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 06:00:00  c       01:00:00
2222   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:21:00  c       00:03:00
2222   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:24:00  a       00:10:00
2222   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 10:34:00  b       00:15:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 00:00:00  c       01:00:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 01:00:00  c       01:00:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 02:00:00  c       01:00:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 03:00:00  c       01:00:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 04:00:00  c       01:00:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 05:00:00  c       01:00:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 06:00:00  c       00:21:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 06:21:00  a       00:03:00      1*
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 06:24:00  b       00:36:00      2*
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 07:00:00  b       01:00:00
3333   2016-12-01  2016-12-01 08:00:00  b       01:00:00
```

I need to be able to pull two specific types of rows (with separate queries is fine/preferable).

1. Where State changes, but EmpID and EventDate remain the same (as the prior row).
2. The first record of a series where State does not change for the remaining EventDate (with constant EmpID and State).

I've added *'s to indicate which I'm looking for. While this data set only contains one date, the actual source contains data spanning over a year at present, and continuing to grow.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: And why don't you want the "2222" records?

Comment: The consecutive records indicate an error of some sort - I need to flag those and determine when the error started (query 2) or ended (query 1). In this case, 2222 had no errors.

Comment: select from 'tablename' as a left join 'tablename' as b on .... You can join on the same table to get what you want. Now, I'd rather normalize this table instead though

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my table to normalize...

Answer (score 0):

Your rules for (1) select more rows than you marked with the 1*.  The one from 4:27, for example.

Here's query (1):

```
SELECT a.*
 FROM tab as a
 JOIN tab as b
 WHERE a.EmpID = b.EmpID
   AND a.EventDate = b.EventDate
   AND a.State <> b.State
   AND b.TimeStamp = (SELECT max(Timestamp) 
                  FROM tab WHERE TimeStamp < a.TimeStamp);
```

And here's query (2). It runs for a while.

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM tab as a
  WHERE (NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM tab as b 
        WHERE a.EmpID = b.EmpID
              AND a.EventDate = b.EventDate
              AND a.State = b.State
              AND b.Timestamp < a.Timestamp))
    AND (NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM tab as b
        WHERE a.EmpID = b.EmpID
          AND a.EventDate = b.EventDate
          AND a.State<> b.State
          AND b.Timestamp > a.Timestamp))
    AND (EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM tab as b 
        WHERE a.EmpID = b.EmpID
          AND a.EventDate = b.EventDate
          AND a.State = b.State
          AND b.Timestamp > a.Timestamp))
```

The three pieces of WHERE in query 2 are:
1. make sure there is no prior record for same emp, date, and state. 
2. make sure there is no future record for same emp and date, with a different state.
3. make sure there is at least one future record for same emp, date, and state (in order words, that a chain was actually started).